# Having problems with float positions on different z index layers

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I want to have:

- the white box on the left side of the green box;
- the purple box fill the rest of the green.

Tried clearing etc. but nothing worked, maybe I didn't do it properly.

I am still a beginner, so the code may not be clean nor properly formatted.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
 background-color: #6CF;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 18px;
}

#upper {
 height: 404px;
 width: 381px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 0px;
 float: left;
 z-index: 2;
}

#wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 900px;
 height: 700px;
 background-color: #C00;
 z-index: 1;
}

#header {
 height:180px;
 background-color: #FC0;
}

#menu {
 height: 36px;
 background-color: #3C0;
}

#break {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

#menu2 {
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #909;
}

#text {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href = "styles/styles3.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<div id = "upper"></div>
<div id = "wrapper">
 <div id = "header"></div>
    <div id = "menu">
     <div id = "break"></div>
        <div id = "menu2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id = "text"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the point of `z-index` here? it's pointless as it'd be applied only to positioned elements.

Comment: Theres gonna be something on the upper layer, that has to be above the others. thats why im using z index, but tell me if im worng.

Comment: Thinking of elements as *layers* makes sense only if they are *positioned*. [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) won't affect non-positioned elements - elements with `static` positioning.

Comment: I see, im going to try something else. But if u try putting somthing on the upper - lets say - div then, its gonna be visible, and yellow,red,green divs gonna be "under" it. So somehow z-index works, or is it something else? –